# 3d cubic spline interpolation in visual c++

Tags: visual-c++, opengl

I'm looking for code and maybe example for the easy understanding of cubic spline Interpolation in visual c++ to use it on openGL. I found some of it but all of them is 2D.

Answer (score 2):

Cubic spline interpolation in 3D is not so much different from what's done in 2D. Only difference is, that the vectors have one additional element.

Could you please post, what you tried so far, or one of the 2D examples you were referring to, so that we can show you, how to expand it to 3D step by step.

Comment: hm.... I got a code from http://www.codeforge.com/article/187073 and used the cubic spline interpolation class to my project.
The class works like if I give 3 points, the class give me back many points of the line.